# Equality of two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, self-learning

For given $D \in \mathbb{R}^{N\times M}$, $\psi\in \mathbb{R}^M$ and $s^0 \in \mathbb{R}^N$, I have the following relationship for all $h\in\mathbb{R}^N$:
$$ h^T s^0 = h^TD\psi$$

Does it imply that:
$$ s^0 = D\psi$$

I want to say yes, but can't seem to write a valid proof.

Comment: @M.Vinay Actually, I don't think your counter-example works here, the first relationship is valid for all $h \in \mathbb{R}^N$. If I take your $s^0$ and $D\psi$ with $h=[1,0,0]^T$, the relationship does not hold anymore.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I missed that it's for all $h$. I'll correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take $h=s_0-D\psi$. You get that $0=h^T(s_0-D\psi)=\|s_0-D\psi\|^2$. Hence $s_0-D\psi=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $h = e^i$, the $i$<sup>th</sup> standard basis vector, which has $1$ as its $i$<sup>th</sup> component and all other components zero. Then for any vector $x \in \mathbb R^n$, $h^T x = x_i$, the $i$<sup>th</sup> component of $x$.

Since for all $h \in \mathbb R^N$, we have $(e^i)^T s^0 = (e^i)^T D\psi$, $i = 1, \ldots, N$, which implies that the $i$<sup>th</sup> component of $s^0$ is the same as the $i$<sup>th</sup> component of $D\psi$ for every $i$, so $s^0 = D\psi$.

---

More succinctly, observe that if $h^T s^0 = h^T D\psi$ for all $h \in \mathbb R^n$, then for any matrix $A \in \mathbb R^{K \times N}$, we have $As^0 = h^T D\psi$ (by comparing columns of the products on both sides). Take $A = I_n \in \mathbb R^{N \times N}$ (identity matrix).